# UIColor.redColor().CGColor in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicolor

`UIColor.redColor().CGColor` is giving error `Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIColor'`

What's has changed in the recent swift version?

Comment: Use `UIColor.red.cgColor`

Comment: "Edit->Convert->To Current Swift Syntax..." fixes that automatically...

Comment: I'm curious as to why you asked this question, as I clicked on it the second it showed up and it had already been answered... By yourself...

Comment: @pkc456 Also try to answer questions as answers rather than as a comment: Check out the **When shouldn't I comment?** section in [Comment Everywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @JacobKing I'm from Legacy ObjC and the above code is commonly used in ObjC but the method name and property is changes in swift 3. I couldn't find this on SO thus answered my own question as a documentation on SO and it's perfectly okay to to this on SO

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The latest swift 3 syntax for `UIColor.redColor().CGColor` is `UIColor.red.cgColor`

The `redColor()` method is changed to `red` getter and `CGColor` property is changed to `cgColor`